# Netty shutdown/Stop UDP server

Tags: java, server, udp, netty, shutdown

I'm trying to create Netty UDP listener. The problem I faced is that I can't stop udp server like tcp, the udp always is running, even with shutdowngracefully called, the only way to stop it is by throwing exception.

```
private int port;
private UDPViewModel viewModel;
private DefaultEventLoopGroup defaultEventLoopGroup;

public UdpServer(UDPViewModel viewModel, int port) {
   this.port = port;
   this.viewModel = viewModel;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    defaultEventLoopGroup = new DefaultEventLoopGroup();
    try {

        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                .channel(UdpServerChannel.class)
                .group(defaultEventLoopGroup)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(Channel channel) {
                        channel.pipeline()
                                .addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5))
                                .addLast(new UdpServerHandler(viewModel));
                    }
                });
        bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().syncUninterruptibly().await();

        System.out.println("UDP Server : [successfully started]");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        defaultEventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Anyone has any ideas on how to shutdown netty udp server properly ?

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I'm assuming you use this [git repo](https://github.com/Shevchik/UdpServerSocketChannel) which by the way is pretty poorly written. Furthermore I would recommend to not use it since UDP isn't intended to be used in a server/client model and all that repo does is *manage* your UDP channels which are not existent since UDP is connectionless. All it really does is to store a fake channel instance which in its core is just a `InetAddress`. What you could do instead is to use a normal thread safe `List` or somesorte of Storage for the different `InetAddress` you wanna cache and just use this.

But if you really need to use this repo you need to stop the `ServerChannel` instance since the `UdpServerChannel` starts a new eventloop which isn't exposed to the outside and can only be stopped when closing the channel. (This is another reason you shouldn't use it, it's wasteful to open multiple `EventLoopGroups` for the same thing)

Comment: so, netty is not suitable for udp server ? No wonder I can't find any good samples of netty and udp...

Answer (score 0):

I guess I founded another way to solve this. 
A solution to my problem, It's not *PERFECT* but it does what I want.

```
public class UdpServer {

private int port;
private UDPViewModel viewModel;
private final EventLoopGroup nioEventLoopGroup;
private ChannelFuture channelFuture;

public UdpServer(UDPViewModel viewModel, int port) {
   this.port = port;
   this.viewModel = viewModel;
    nioEventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("UDP Server is starting.");
    try{
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(nioEventLoopGroup)
                .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(Channel channel) {
                        channel.pipeline().addLast(
                                new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO),
                                new StringEncoder(), new StringDecoder());
                        channel.pipeline().addLast(
                                new UdpServerHandler(viewModel));
                    }
                });
        channelFuture = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();

    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("UDP listener was interrupted and shutted down");
        e.getCause();
    }
}

public void StopServer()
{
    try {
        nioEventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

close it in the UdpServerHandler

notice

```
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet)
```

call `ctx.close()`